# SpriteKit NSTimeInterval renamed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit, cocoapods

I'm trying to use SpriteKit in my project but after I install it and open the project I get 28 errors. I tried to rename the 'NSTimeInterval' to 'TimeInterval' but it didn't work. I'm using Xcode 9.3

This is my Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Aaa' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Aaa
    pod 'SpriteKit-Spring'
end
```

I get these errors (27 are the same - 'NSTimeInterval' has been renamed to 'TimeInterval'):
[Error list screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d99WL.png)

**Solution:**
In the Podfile have this line:

```
pod 'SpriteKit-Spring', :git => 'https://github.com/ataugeron/SpriteKit-Spring/'
```

Comment: You are looking for a miracle here, do what the error tells you to do and continue until you see it no more. If you do not own SpriteKit-Spring, then obviously the answer is to talk to the owner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SpriteKit-Spring hasn't been updated to Swift 4, at least not the released pod. See  https://github.com/ataugeron/SpriteKit-Spring/issues/12 for a workaround.

Comment: Thanks! Found an solution there.